# Django Imagefield url does not contain MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: python, django, image

I have a model with a ImageField and created an simple Upload Form via CreateForm. I have a simple ListView to show the images (logos).

Upload works fine, Iterating the logos works. Property logo.url is missing but instead it is logo.media. Unfortunately media does not contain the whole path, MEDIA_ROOT is missing. What am I doing wrong here?

models.py:

```
class Logo(models.Model):
    media = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

views.py:

```
class LogoManager(CreateView):
  model = Logo
  template_name = 'polls/upload.html'
  success_url = '/logos/'

class LogoIndex(ListView):
  model = Logo
  template_name = 'polls/logos.html'
```

upload.html:

```
{% block title %} Upload Form {% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<form id="my_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
<br />
<a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">Back</a>
{% endblock %}
```

logos.html:

```
{% block content %}
  {% if object_list %}
    <ul>
      {% for image in object_list %}
        <li><img src="{{ image.media }}" width="320" height="200"/></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>No Logos are available.</p>
  {% endif %}
<br />
{% endblock %}
```

Output is:

```
<li><img src="uploads/IMG_5106.JPG" width="320" height="200"/></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `{{ image.media.url }}`, I think.

Comment: Tried with:

    <li><img src="{{ image.media.url }}" width="320" height="200"/></li>

Output remains:

    <li><img src="uploads/IMG_5106.JPG" width="320" height="200"/></li>

Comment: Have you defined `MEDIA_URL` in your configuration too?

Comment: No, its not defined. For what reason?

Comment: OK, the path is now shown the right way, thanks.
Only problem remains, the pictures are not found. urls.py already contains the django.views.static.serve.

urls.py:

    url(r'^/media/(?P<path>.*)', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT }),

Comment: did you add '+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)' to your urls?

Comment: Is this really necessary to put the MEDIA_URL in each file reference? I thought the loader mechanism django.views.static.serve takes care of that?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was my wrong. I was editing the url in the apps url file. When adding this stanza in root urls.py it works fine:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.static',
    (r'%s(?P<path>.*)' % settings.MEDIA_URL, 'serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

using settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL =  '/media/'
```

Comment: Update, because I didn't reload the app after chaning the setting.py

It needs to be `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'` (without trailing slash) to work.